# Redirecting requests from domain to local server

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns, spoofing

I'm developing a web application for a pre-production hardware device which has the domain from which it loads the app hard-coded. Is there a (simple) way for me to reroute these requests to a local development server?

I've been trying to get something working with a local instance of PowerDNS and then changing the DNS server setting of my broadband router to point to this instead. But despite spending more than a days worth of time on it I've been unable to get the DNS server working (I am not a network admin and don't really know what I'm doing here!), so I'm looking for an easier alternative.

Many thanks in advance,

JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question completely but you can do this if you running your own DNS server.  In the DNS server, add the domain you want to redirect and then add an A record for the hostname with the local IP you want to redirect to.

Forward Lookup Zone:         AppLoadDomain.com
Host Record:           A   Host1.AppLoadDomain.com   1.2.3.4

If the device is using DHCP then you'll need to change "DNS Server" setting in the DHCP Server scope (probably running on the broadband router) to point to the IP of the internal DNS server, not your broadband router.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ed! This is what I've been trying to do: I have PowerDNS installed, pointing to a MySQL DB where I've added a zone for the domain as well as an A record pointing to my local dev server's IP. But I can't get PowerDNS to work properly and the documentation is wafer thin. Are there any DNS servers that are easier to set up?

Comment: I work in the MS world so I use the built in DNS server in MS servers.  I'm not familiar with PowerDNS so I can't offer any help.  This may provide some options: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software
Keep it simple and use text files for the backend. Unless you are dealing with many many zones there is no need for a db backend.
Make sure the firewall is off on the DNS server and use nslookup or digg (depending on your OS) to test.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I've managed to get things working using Bind instead of PowerDNS (funny, I was adviced against using Bind for its complexity, but it actually turned out being the easier option I was looking for).

Comment: I am glad its working!